# Simple Proofs in ZFC Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, axioms

So I'll keep this real short and simple. In [this document](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf) on page 23 there is a list of axioms. On page 24 there is a list of theorems that come from said axioms. I can prove them all except 3 and 5. I feel like it's not hard and I just don't have enough experience with manipulating logic formulae for the answer to be clear. If someone could post the proofs for 3 and 5 I would appreciate it very much.

The list of axioms that are used:

1. $\forall x \forall y\, \left[ x = y \rightarrow (\forall z: (x \in z \leftrightarrow y \in z)\,\right]$
2. $\forall x \forall y\, \left[ x = y \leftrightarrow (\forall z: (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \right]$
3. $\exists z \,z = \emptyset$
4. $\forall x \forall y \exists z\, z = \{x,y\}$

Theorem 1.3: $\forall x \forall y \forall z \left[ (x=y \land y = z) \rightarrow x=z  \right]$ (the documents says this one comes solely from the Axiom of Extensionality (axiom 2 above)

Theorem 1.5:  $\forall u \forall v \forall x \forall y \left[\langle u,v \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle \leftrightarrow (u=x \land v=y)\right] $

where $\langle s,t \rangle$ is defined to be $\{\{s\}, \{s,t\}\}$.

Comment: If you can please actually write down what theorems 3 and 5 are, so people won't have to go to great lengths to help you for absolutely no return, it would be great.

Comment: Presumably $\emptyset$ was also defined earlier, so that Axiom 3 makes sense.

Comment: Yes, as $\{v: \lnot(v=v)\}$, but is treated as a class.

Comment: I'm sorry, It was pretty early when I posted this. Also I didn't know how to use LaTeX in a post.